# Scheduled job in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I have a cron expression set in the application properties file as follows:

```
report.monthlyScheduleTime=0 10 07 1W * ?
```

and annotated like the following,

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${report.monthlyScheduleTime}", zone="${report.scheduleTimeZone}")
```

But when ran the application, I got the following exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid
>   @Scheduled method 'ReportJob': For input string: "1W".

Spring Boot seems to not accept `1W` defined in the cron expression. Any idea why?

Comment: Here is a link to the QUARTZ cron trigger tutorial, and '1W' is a valid value for day of month. It seems Spring Boot not compatible with QUAETZ.

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spring Boot seems to not accept 1W defined in the cron expression. Any idea why?

`1W` is specific to Quartz, but you are not using Quartz.

---

Your cron expression (`0 10 07 1W * ?`) is correct based on the [Quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html):

> The ‘W’ is used to specify the weekday (Monday-Friday) nearest the given day. As an example, if you were to specify “15W” as the value for the day-of-month field, the meaning is: “the nearest weekday to the 15th of the month”.

But the pattern `1W` is specific to Quartz.

With [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--), you are using Spring's own scheduling support. This allows expression based on [Crontab pattern](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) but has no support for `1W`.

So you either need to actually use Quartz or modify your cron expression. If you want to use Quartz, in [Spring documentation on scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), the section "Using the Quartz Scheduler" describes Spring's support for Quartz. However, if you want to modify cron expression, you can refer to [`CronSequenceGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

Answer (score 0):

not sure what cron you wanted to create, but maybe these examples will help you understand your issue:

```
Example patterns:

"0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
"*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
"0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
"0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
"0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```

Comment: I wanted to run the job on the 1st weekday of every month.

Comment: try this: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 ? 1/1 MON#1 *")
it's 10AM for every first monday of the month

Comment: That not what I wanted, for example, May 1st is Tuesday, I wanted it to run on Tuesday, not the next Monday.

Comment: now I understand. don't think there's an easy way out here. what about this: if it's monday, it should work if it's 1st\2nd\3rd of the month (as an example, if it's the 3rd, the 1st was friday) so the cron here is something like 
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 1,2,3 * MON") 

    and then the rest is if any other weekday is the first of the month:
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 1 * TUE-THU")

Comment: '1W' means first weekday, it is valid notation for day of month, but not sure why Spring Boot does not take it, is this a bug in Spring Boot?

Comment: The cron expression is correct and was validated on the CronMaker site.

Comment: spring cron doesn't follow the same format as UNIX cron.
the solution I gave you works...